# python run 3 while loops indefinitely

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, indefinite

I am trying to make the 3 while loops run indefinitely, but right now when the while player == 2 loop ends, the variable player = 0 due to the function, but the loop does not go back to the first while loop.

```
def nextplayer():
    global player
    if player == 0:
        player = 1
    elif player ==1:
        player = 2
    elif player == 2:
        player = 0

while player == 0:
    print('Player 1 turn')
    spinwheel()
    nextplayer()

while player == 1:
    print('Player 2 turn')
    spinwheel()
    nextplayer()

while player == 2:
    print('Player 3 turn')
    spinwheel()
    nextplayer()
```

Comment: Maybe you just want a `while True` and then `if player == 0`, etc?

Comment: There are likely better ways of setting this up, but if you want those three loops to repeat, why not just put them in a loop?

Comment: `while True: if player ==0 elif player ==1 elif player ==2 else break`

Answer (score 0):

This would be much simpler with `itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle


for player in cycle([0,1,2]):
    print(f'Player {player} turn')
    spinwheel()
```

No need to call a function `nextplayer` that mutates a global variable.